# jQuery click not work

Tags: jquery

I have a simple code which uses JQuery.

When I click the text given (`grjvtrjv`) I want it to change to another text(`sdfds` in this case)

But it isn't working. Please help.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <p class="fg">grjvtrjv</p>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".fg").click(function(){
 $(".fg").html("sdfds");
}
</script>
</html>
```

NOTE: no php used, but file's extension is `.php`

Comment: i dont see any php. you also have a simple syntax error - check your console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your click function hasn't been written correctly. Your missing a `)` after the final `}`. I'd also put it in the document ready function.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <p class="fg">grjvtrjv</p>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $(".fg").click(function(){
            $(".fg").html("sdfds");
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```html
    <html>
 <body>
  <p class="fg">grjvtrjv</p>
 </body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).on("click",".fg",function(){
   $(this).html("sdfds");
  });
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: more simple `$(".fg").on("click",function(){$(this).html("sdfds");});`

Comment: @NamanTujis you were missing the final closing parenthesis, I also took the liberty of improving the performance of the code

Comment: @godmode Where was I missing the closing parenthesis?

Comment: your click method should have been, 

`$(".fg").click(function(){
 $(".fg").html("sdfds");
});`